# WebRTC - Detecting if the camera stopped

Tags: webrtc

WebRTC Questions

- Is there an event for when the users camera stops streaming prematurely?
- WebRTC can connect Peer2Peer what about Peer1 having a stream and multiple observers viewing?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand your second part....do you meant like this? ... https://webrtc-experiment.appspot.com/broadcast/ ... this experiment broadcasts video over unlimited peers....

Answer (score 1):

My experiment with Chrome 24 and 26 show that none of the mediastream/localmediastream or video events fire when a peer disconnects, but the (RTCPeerConnection) icecandidate event does fire several times right after the disconnect: first with the candidate and then without it on the event object.

```
peer = new RTCPeerConnection({ "iceServers": [{ "url": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" }] });
peer.onicecandidate = function(e){
   if(!e.candidate) return console.log('Did someone disconnect?',e);
   console.log('Someone might have just disconnected. Or maybe not.',e);
}
```

I've been able to connect 3 peers in chrome successfully as well: as far as I know each peer connection just connects two peers, so to have multiple simultaneous connections the host connects with each one individually.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you wanted:

```
(await peerConnection.getStats())
  .forEach((c)=>{if(c.type =='track')console.log(c)})
```

That will tell you how many frames have been received. Store that and then ask a second later and compare the two results. if the number of frames is the same it is not getting new data.